# How to feed an async generator with events from python.net

Tags: python, .net, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python.net

I am using a third party .Net library in Python 3.6 via Python for .Net which uses EventHandlers to provide asynchronous data to my application, similar to the toy example below:

```py
import clr
from System import Timers

def tock(__, args):
    print(args.SignalTime)

timer = Timers.Timer()
timer.Interval = 1000
timer.Elapsed += tock
timer.Enabled = True
while True:
    pass
```

I would like to get this data into an asynchronous generator, something like:

```py
import clr
from System import Timers

async def tock(__, args):
    yield args.SignalTime

async def main():
    result = await tock
    print(result)

timer = Timers.Timer()
timer.Interval = 1000
timer.Elapsed += tock
timer.Enabled = True
while true:
    result = await timer
    print result
```

Obiviously just throwing `asyc` and `yield` on the event handler function and `await`ing the timer won't do it, but is there a straightforward means of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the "asynchronous" data comes from another thread, you will need a bridge between asyncio and the thread that invokes `tock`. On the asyncio side, you will need to implement an async generator and iterate over it with an `async for` loop. For example (untested):

```
import clr, asyncio
from System import Timers

def adapt_sync_to_async():
    # Adapt a series of sync callback invocations to an async
    # iterator. Returns an async iterator and a feed callback
    # such that the async iterator will produce a new item
    # whenever the feed callback is fed one.
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    def feed(item):
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, item)
    async def drain():
        while True:
            yield await queue.get()
    return drain, feed

tock, feed_tock = adapt_sync_to_async()

async def main():
    async for result in tock():
        print(result)

timer = Timers.Timer()
timer.Interval = 1000
timer.Elapsed += lambda _, args: feed_tock(args.SignalTime)
timer.Enabled = True

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thank you, that solution works (after adding the `import asyncio` that I forgot initially)